# Git restore - error: pathspec '.' did not match any file(s) known to git

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm getting `error: pathspec '.' did not match any file(s) known to git` when I run `git restore .`, how can I resolve this and revert all the current changes?

Comment: Do you have any commits? In an existing repository `git restore .` works fine. But in a new freshly created repo righ after `git init` the command produced the same error.

Answer (score 1):

This will occur if the current directory is untracked. `git restore :/` will operate on the root of the repo rather than the current directory, so will still succeed if you are in a subfolder of the repository that is untracked unless the repository was not committed since initialisation.